# WPF Canvas/Path in Style not duplicated

Tags: wpf, resources, styles

I've got the following problem. I defined a button style to set the appearance of my button using a Path. The style seems to work greatly, but if I apply it to more than one button, the Path occurs just in one of them. Here's my style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNew" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Canvas x:Key="Button_New_Normal" Width="24" Height="24" >
                <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M13,7H11V11H7V13H11V17H13V13H17V11H13V7Z" Fill="Black" />
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas x:Key="Button_New_MouseOver" Width="24" Height="24" >
                <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M13,7H11V11H7V13H11V17H13V13H17V11H13V7Z" Fill="Gray" />
        </Canvas>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Button_New_Normal}}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="template" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="Green">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Button_New_MouseOver}}" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'm pretty sure there are more elegant ways to work with those paths but that's not my problem now. Anyway, here's how I apply the style:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleNew}" Width="40" Margin="0,0,20,0"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleNew}" Width="40"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now, the path occurs in the right button only, in the left one only the green border occurs. If I move the mouse over the left button, the path moves from the right to the left button and stays there. Moving the mouse again over the right button moves the path back to it.

It seems that the Canvas/Path resource is allocated only once and not for each of the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the [x:Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) attribute to of the `Canvas` to `false`:

```
<Canvas x:Key="Button_New_Normal" x:Shared="False" Width="24" Height="24" >
```

You should also define the `Canvas` resources as separate resources outside of `<Style.Resources>`.

You also don't need to involve a `ContentControl`. You could set the `Content` to the `Canvas` resources directly. This works:

```
<Canvas x:Key="Button_New_Normal" x:Shared="False"  Width="24" Height="24" >
    <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M13,7H11V11H7V13H11V17H13V13H17V11H13V7Z" Fill="Black" />
</Canvas>
<Canvas x:Key="Button_New_MouseOver"   x:Shared="False" Width="24" Height="24" >
    <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M13,7H11V11H7V13H11V17H13V13H17V11H13V7Z" Fill="Gray" />
</Canvas>

<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNew" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Button_New_Normal}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate x:Name="template" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="Green">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="Button_New_MouseOver" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the ContentControl vs. Content. I'm pretty new with WPF and try to figure it you yet. Using x:Shared="False" gives me an exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Shared attribute in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries.'

Comment: @PeterDeussen: Did you really move the Canvas resources out of <Style.Resources> as per my sample code then?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact details, but when I have worked with static instances of controls, I have had similar behaviors. I have found that using DataTemplates was a way to work around this:

**Updated Style**

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNew" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Button_New_Normal">
                <Canvas Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M13,7H11V11H7V13H11V17H13V13H17V11H13V7Z" Fill="Black" />
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="Button_New_MouseOver">
                <Canvas Width="24" Height="24" >
                    <Path Data="M12,20C7.59,20 4,16.41 4,12C4,7.59 7.59,4 12,4C16.41,4 20,7.59 20,12C20,16.41 16.41,20 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2M13,7H11V11H7V13H11V17H13V13H17V11H13V7Z" Fill="Gray" />
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>

        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Button_New_Normal}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate x:Name="template" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border Background="Green">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Button_New_MouseOver}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Demo**

[image: Demo]

Comment: Great, thanks! Works like a charm. Highly appreciated